# Python RE Directories and slashes

Tags: python, python-re

Let's say I have a string that is a root directory that has been entered

```
'C:/Users/Me/'
```

Then I use `os.listdir()` and join with it to create a list of subdirectories.

I end up with a list of strings that are like below:

```
'C:/Users/Me/Adir\Asubdir\'
```

and so on.

I want to split the subdirectories and capture each directory name as its own element.  Below is one attempt.  I am seemingly having issues with the `\` and `/` characters.  I assume `\` is escaping, so `'[\\/]'` to me that says look for `\` or `/` so then `'[\\/]([\w\s]+)[\\/]'` as a match pattern should look for any word between two slashes...  but the output is only `['/Users/']` and nothing else is matched.  So I then I add a escape for the forward slash.

`'[\\\/]([\w\s]+)[\\\/]'`

However, my output then only becomes `['Users','ADir']` so that is confusing the crud out of me.

My question is namely how do I tokenize each directory from a string using both `\` and `/` but maybe also why is my RE not working as I expect?

Minimal Example:

```
import re, os

info = re.compile('[\\\/]([\w ]+)[\\\/]')


root = 'C:/Users/i12500198/Documents/Projects/'

def getFiles(wdir=os.getcwd()):
    files = (os.path.join(wdir,file) for file in os.listdir(wdir)
                 if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(wdir,file)))
    return list(files)

def getDirs(wdir=os.getcwd()):
    dirs = (os.path.join(wdir,adir) for adir in os.listdir(wdir)
                if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(wdir,adir)))
    return list(dirs)

def walkSubdirs(root,below=[]):
    subdirs = getDirs(root)
    for aDir in subdirs:
        below.append(aDir)
        walkSubdirs(aDir,below)       
        
    return below   

subdirs = walkSubdirs(root)
    
for aDir in subdirs:
    files = getFiles(aDir)
    for f in files:
        finfo = info.findall(f)
        print(f)
        print(finfo)
```

Comment: How did you get `'C:/Users/Me/Adir\Asubdir\'` out of Python? That's not a valid string.

Comment: Added an update to clarify.  I am using walking and using os.join to join strings returned by os.listdir

Comment: Oh, so it's not a string, it's the printed output. Please clarify that.

Comment: Sorry boss.  Would have if I knew that.  I assumed it was a string.  I learned a couple things today with this question...

Comment: Ah OK, you should learn some more about data vs its representation. Check out [Why do backslashes appear twice?](/q/24085680/4518341)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to split the subdirectories and capture each directory name as its own element

Instead of regular expressions, I suggest you use one of Python's standard functions for parsing filesystem paths.

Here is one using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html):

```py
from pathlib import Path

p = Path("C:/Users/Me/ADir\ASub Dir\2 x 2 Dir\\")
p.parts
#=> ('C:\\', 'Users', 'Me', 'ADir', 'ASub Dir\x02 x 2 Dir')
```

Note that the behaviour of `pathlib.Path` depends on the system running Python. Since I'm on a Linux machine, I actually used [`pathlib.PureWindowsPath`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PureWindowsPath) here. I believe the output should be accurate for those of you on Windows.